# Possible to use multiple JQuery Mobile swatches in the same page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themes, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I'm trying to use multiple JQuery Mobile swatches/themes on different widgets on a single page.

E.g. : my page has theme 'a' while some button needs theme 'b'

I tried setting different `data-theme` attributes on the page and the button but the button still shows the same theme as the page.

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you are using jQM 1.4, you add the class ui-btn-b to your buttons. See example in jQM demos: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/button-markup/

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I used the theme roller with different theme on the same page and it worked.

If you use the 1.4.2 version check if you use in the code the class attribute `class="ui-btn-g"` for example if you created a "g" theme in the theme roller.

Check also if you include the css file needed.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/mytheme.min.css" />`

I had problem in the past because I not included the good .css file. I know that there were 2 .css file in the folder that we dowload from the theme roller website, check if you include the good one. I know that nowdays they give a test html page to see and explain how to include.

Hopping this help you.